# Replicating the WP_Query 's' param with $wpdb

Tags: wpdb, plugin-polylang

Take this basic query:

```
$posts = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'page'
    's' => 'some search query'
));
```

WordPress will split the `some search query` into 3 separate search terms, which is why I need to make this $wpdb function. I want the same functionality, but with the entire query treated as 1 search term.

Here is where I'm at:

```
global $wpdb;
$post_type = 'product';

$db_matches = $wpdb->get_results("
                                    SELECT ID
                                    FROM $wpdb->posts
                                    INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id = $wpdb->posts.post_title
                                    WHERE post_title LIKE '%$query%'
                                        AND post_type = '$post_type'
                                        AND post_status = 'publish'
                                    ");
```

This is my first inner join ever, so it's probably all wrong. Two things need to be done to fix this query:

1. Fix the syntax in the inner join line
2. Add the language filter in the `WHERE` clauses (should be something like `AND term_taxonomy_id = 2`, right?). I'm using Polylang, so I just need to check that the `object_id` exists in the `term_relationships` table with the value `2`.

So can anyone give me a hand with this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This appears to be an XY problem, can you explain what you were trying to achieve that required this SQL? It would make more sense to ask about what you're trying to do, than asking about fixing your solution, e.g. it looks like you're unaware that `WP_Query` can check taxonomies too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It seems that you in your INNER JOIN, you are joining on

   ```
   wp_term_relationships.object_id == wp_posts.post_title
   ```

   which is erroneous, since ***object_id*** is the post-id in this case-scenario.

   *I want all IDs (post-ids)*

   ```
   SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts
   ```

   *Who have a record in the wp_term_relationships table*

   ```
   // Now we are comparing the correct columns
   INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id = $wpdb->posts.ID
   ```
2. Adding the additional where clause

   *Where the term_taxonomy_id is equal to 2*

   ```
   WHERE $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 2
   ```

Answer (score 1):

> WordPress will split the some search query into 3 separate search
>   terms, which is why I need to make this $wpdb function. I want the
>   same functionality, but with the entire query treated as 1 search
>   term.

There are the `sentence` and `exact` input search parameters for `WP_Query`.

Instead of manually constructing the search query yourself, please try e.g.

```
$query = new WP_Query( [
    'post_type' => 'page',
    's'         => 'some search query',
    'sentence'  => true,
    'exact'     => true,
] );
```

The generated SQL query will include:

```
(wp_posts.post_title LIKE 'some search query') OR 
(wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE 'some search query') OR 
(wp_posts.post_content LIKE 'some search query')
```

With `exact` as `false`, it will change to:

```
(wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%some search query%') OR 
(wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%some search query%') OR 
(wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%some search query%')
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Wow. I really wish that `sentence` and `exact` were in the docs...

Comment: The best documentation is the [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/a2693fd8602e3263b5925b9d799ddd577202167d/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L681) @Brian